# Binding Expression Error When Binding to Nullable Int32

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, dependency-properties, nullable

So I think I found a really interesting bug in the UWP platform.

If I have a `textbox` and I bind its `Text` property to a `int?` dependency property, then I get the following exception. It doesn't seem to matter if my consumer binds a nullable int or nonnullable int to the control, the same error is displayed. It looks like it's directly related to the dependency property being nullable.

```
Error: Converter failed to convert value of type 'Windows.Foundation.Int32' 
to type 'IReference`1<Int32>'; BindingExpression: Path='MyNotNullableInt' 
DataItem='ControlSandbox.FooViewModel'; target element is 
'ControlSandbox.NumericTextBox' (Name='null'); 
target property is 'Value' (type 'IReference`1<Int32>').
```

I'm not even using a converter so I'm guessing this is something happening in the guts of the framework. The example code below will produce the output

**Main.xaml**

```
    <Grid Background="White" >
        <local:NumericTextBox Value="{Binding MyNotNullableInt, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
```

**Main.xaml.cs**

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new FooViewModel();
        }
    }
```

**FooViewModel.cs**

```
  public class FooViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _myNotNullableInt;

        public int MyNotNullableInt
        {
            get { return _myNotNullableInt; }
            set { _myNotNullableInt = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyNotNullableInt"); }
        }

        private int? _myNullableInt;

        public int? MyNullableInt
        {
            get { return _myNullableInt; }
            set { _myNullableInt = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyNullableInt"); }
        }


        public FooViewModel()
        {
            MyNullableInt = null;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
    }
```

**NumericTextBox.xaml**

```
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind Value}" />
    </Grid>
```

**NumericTextBox.xaml.cs**

```
 public sealed partial class NumericTextBox : UserControl
    {
        public int? Value
        {
            get { return (int?)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int?), typeof(NumericTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(0));

        public NumericTextBox()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I'm not sure why this page didn't come back in our initial hours of research on the error, however, at least this post now will document this for the future.

I was looking into binding to nullable dependency properties and I came across [this article](https://www.danrigby.com/2012/07/24/windows-8-dev-tip-nullable-dependency-properties-and-binding/)

> Turns out that under the covers most of the .NET primitive types are
>   converted to equivalent Windows Runtime types. IReference happens to
>   be the Windows Runtime equivalent of Nullable in .NET.

It says, that you need to change the property type `typeof`on the dependency property from your nullable type to `object`

I've confirmed this works.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(object), typeof(NumericTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```